# Calling method with arguments using __getattr__()

Tags: python, class, methods, getattr

Recently, I saw the code below as an answer to a problem:

```
class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            value = getattr(self._obj, attr)
        except Exception:
            raise Exception('No Such Method')
        else:
            return value

class Tmp:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def set_num(self, num):
        self.num = num
        print(self.num)

tmp = Tmp(10)
tmp_proxy = Proxy(tmp)
tmp_proxy.set_num(12)
```

As you can see, it uses `tmp_proxy` to call `set_num()` method of object  `tmp`. But I can't understand how it passes the argument `num` to this method, because as we print `attr` and its type, we see this:

```
set_num
<class 'str'>
```

How does this work?

Comment: What exactly isn't clear? if you remove `return ...` from `__getattr__` then it will implicitly return `None` for any `.` notation access so `tmp_proxy.set_num` is `None`. Also, the title and the question are not related

Comment: Try to add some breakpoints and debug your code step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tmp_proxy` doens't *call* `set_num`; it provides a reference to the appropriate bound method. `value` is that bound method, not the return value. You could rewrite this code more explicitly:

```
f = tmp_proxy.set_num  # get a bound method
f(12)  # call the bound method
```